# Ruby on Rails: Send JSON data from server to client asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

**Background and my research**

I would like to send data from server to client without reloading the page on the browser. I was reading [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and using JSON seemed promising. (Correct me if I am wrong).

> 2.2.8 Rendering JSON
>
> JSON is a JavaScript data format used by many AJAX libraries. Rails
>   has built-in support for converting objects to JSON and rendering that
>   JSON back to the browser:
>
> render :json => @product You don’t need to call to_json on the object
>   that you want to render. If you use the :json option, render will
>   automatically call to_json for you.

---

**Problem**

I want to be able to render this JSON object back in the browser side. The following are appropriate code for the problem.

**VideosController**

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  include VideosHelper

  def home
    @video = Video.last
  end

  def next
    @next_video = next_video(params[:id])
    render :json => @next_video
  end
end
```

**next.json.erb**

```
{
  "title": "<%= @video.title %>"
  "url": "<%= @video.url %>"
  "youtube_id": "<%= @video.youtube_id %>"
  "genre": "<%= @video.genre %>"
  "category": "<%= @video.category %>"
  "likes": "<%= @video.likes %>"
  "dislikes": "<%= @video.dislikes %>"
  "views": "<%= @video.views %>"
  "user_id": "<%= @video.user_id %>"
  "created_at": "<%= @video.created_at %>"
  "updated_at": "<%= @video.updated_at %>"
}
```

If I want to render `@next_video` JSON object on `home` action. How do I do this?

Comment: Will params[:id] be available on the home action?

Comment: Any reason you're not following REST?

Comment: For UX reasons. I want to change from one video to another without reloading the page because user may be filling out form on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some js handler i guess. Something like that in home.html.erb:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<%= next_video_path(@video.id) %>',
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    // something brilliant here 
  }
})
```

also in next.json.erb you should change @video to @next_video(since you don't have @video initialized in next action). Also one more suggestion - you can use REST those renaming next to show and deleting home(since you can replace it with show now) and you will need to change previous code to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<%= video_path(@video.next) %>',
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    // something brilliant here 
  }
})
```

Where @video.next will return id of the next video.